This reflect algorithm does not reflect image but passes through checking system
I don't understand why this code passes the checking system, but
don't actually work on the image I give it to the algorithm, the image come out same.
This is the report:

:) reflect correctly filters 1x2 image
:) reflect correctly filters 1x3 image
:) reflect correctly filters image that is its own mirror image
:) reflect correctly filters 3x3 image
:( reflect correctly filters 4x4 image expected "100 110 120\n7...",
not "10 20 30\n70
8..." *(except this one)*


Output Image: https://i.sstatic.net/6xZizOBM.png
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            RGBTRIPLE temp;
            if( j != width - j)
            {
                temp = image[i][j];
                image[i][j] = image[i][width - j - 1];
                image[i][width - j - 1] = temp;
            }

            if( j == width - j - 1)
            {
                j = width;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}


If you have the input given, then it's easy to create a [mre] with the input hard-coded, and then debug your program. For example by using a debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

And note that the code does not "passes the checking system". It failes for the 4x4 image test.

The final if-statement is weird.  You could use break instead of the assignment, but it would be better to alter the loop control to test j <= width / 2.  You could then eliminate the other if test too.  (I'm vacillating on < vs <=; but you should check which is correct.)

Note that j == width - j - 1 is never true for widths that are even. The final if doesn't always do what you think it does.

The code has problems:

the test if( j != width - j) is incorrect as the pixels swapped are at index values j and width - j - 1.  The swapping code is a no-op if these values are identical so you can remove this test completely, which will increase performance.
the hack if (j == width - j - 1) { j = width; } does not work if width is even as j never equals width - j - 1. In such cases the image is swapped twice except for the 2 middle columns which are not swapped at all, resulting in the image being unchanged.

You can solve this problem using 2 index variables running in opposite directions:
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0, k = width - 1; j < k; j++, k--)
        {
            RGBTRIPLE temp = image[i][j];
            image[i][j] = image[i][k];
            image[i][k] = temp;
        }
    }
}


@MandarGurav: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.
